# GIT problemas con eliminar cambios temporales

Tags: git

Estuve, 'sin saberlo', creando cambios temporales y como no hice ninguna acción para guardar esos cambios o eliminarlos ahora tengo 5000 cambios no guardados, que tampoco puedo eliminar (todos esos cambios).

Estuve haciendo varias cosas como instalar **plugins** y al parecer me estuvo guardando todo lo que hacia con el editor y por eso tengo 5000 cambios que no sé cómo eliminar.

Estoy empezando con **Git** y esto es muy frustrante, espero alguien pueda ayudarme.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pero que problema es? puedes guardar los cambios haciendo un commit... puedes eliminar cambios (de archivo completo) con un checkout del archivo...

Comment: Quieres revertir tus cambios (perderlos)? o quieres commitearlos y que queden en el historial del repositorio, dejando lo que tienes ahora como la "última versión" del proyecto?

Comment: como dije antes no puedo eliminar ninguno de esos cambios, intente hacerlo de uno en uno o eliminar todos a las vez pero no puedo, me sale el error que vez ahi en pantalla tambien intente hacer commit a todo y regresar a la rama principal y otros comandos mas, definitivamente tendre que desinstalarlo y volver a instalar pero si puedes decrime como evitar que este memorizando todo lo que hago con el editor en cada momento y detener el proceso me ayudaria mucho para seguir mis clases sin que el git me haga este tipo de cosas

Comment: @RichardCvosMilnvr el problema es que no te entendemos.. git sigue todos los ficheros dentro de un repo de git. Donde está tu repo de git? en la raiz? si es así es normal que cualquier cambio en el disco te lo guarde..

Lo normal sería borrar ese repo y crearlo en una carpeta de "trabajo" para que solo siga esos cambios

Comment: Si el objetivo es eliminar cambios que hayas hecho, entonces, debes primero escribir `git log --oneline` y observer el _hash_ donde se encuentra el cambio donde deseas pararte.

Una vez identificado el lugar, proceda a eliminar los cambios así:
`git reset --hard <tu-hash>`.

Recuerda que esta acción no se puede deshacer, por lo tanto, te recomiendo hacer una copia de seguridad antes de realizar la acción antes mencionada.

Answer (score 0):

> **Muy importante:**
>
> No sé si el autor de la pregunta habrá resuelto el problema de los cambios temporales con `Git`, pero daré mi respuesta con el objeto de ayudar a otras personas a solucionarlos.

### Eliminar cambios hechos con **Git**

Para eliminar los cambios hechos con **Git**, primero debemos revisar hasta qué punto queremos eliminar y para lograr ese objetivo, debemos escribir el siguiente comando:

```bash
git log --oneline
```

Que nos devolverá una salida similar a la siguiente:

```
4144c30 (HEAD -> dev, origin/master, origin/dev, origin/HEAD, dlunamontilla/master, dlunamontilla/dev, master) Implementación parcial de la página de contacto
48107cc Se actualiza la apariencia del formulario contacto | Segunda parte
a211e0e Se actualiza la apariencia del formulario | Parte 1
411b9bc Implementación parcial del formulario de contacto
acaad0e Se actualiza la apariencia del título
b9dc244 Actualizaciones de banner

...

6e3886b Git inicial
```

Para visualizar el historial de cambios que hemos hecho.

Luego, nos ubicamos en el lugar que queremos dejar intacto, por ejemplo:

```
git checkout a211e0e
```

Donde `a211e0e` es el hash que tiene el cambio descrito como se cita en el siguiente texto:

> *Se actualiza la apariencia del formulario | Parte 1*

Con el objeto de asegurarnos de que el lugar al que queremos llegar sea el correcto.

Una vez que hayas verificado que los cambios son los correctos, entonces, procedemos a eliminar los cambios que no queremos.

Bien sean, que lo eliminemos de forma reversible:

```
git reset a211e0e
```

O de forma irreversible:

```
git reset --hard a211e0e
```

> Tome en cuenta, que para el segundo caso, si no estás seguro, utilice el primero o en su defecto, haga una copia de seguridad.