# Problema con git bash

Tags: git, bash, git-bash

Tengo un problema con mi terminal. Es la segunda vez que me sucede lo mismo.

El problema son la cantidad de cambios que me registra `bash`, creo que le habré hecho `git add .` en una carpeta que no correspondía, quizás por error o no lo se.

La vez anterior que me ha sucedido perdí todos los archivos que involucraban estos cambios. son más de 10 mil cambios.

He intentado hacerles `git stash` y no se han ido esos cambios. Me interesa poder quitarlos y que no vuelvan.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?, saludos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, Kevin. Si lo que deseas es eliminar los cambios que has hecho puede [encontrar la respuesta aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/367873/git-problemas-con-eliminar-cambios-temporales/590835#590835 "Eliminar cambios, sean temporales o no")

Answer (score 0):

Primero haz un archivo `.gitignore` donde puedas poner las carpetas y archivos que no desees, dale *add* y luego *commit* al archivo. Luego elimina los archivos de tu index con `git rm --cached <archivos>`.

Por ejemplo, voy a tratar de simular lo que es tu caso:

1. Tengo dos carpetas: una de deseables y otra de indeseables:

```bash
$ ls -1
deseables
indeseable
```

2. Di un `git add .` por pelotudo, y encima di `git commit` sin revisar los archivos añadidos con `git status`.

Y cuando doy un `git ls-tree HEAD -r` tengo todos estos archivos:

```bash
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    deseables/archivo_deseable_1      
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    deseables/archivo_deseable_2      
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    deseables/archivo_deseable_3      
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    deseables/archivo_deseable_4      
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    indeseables/archivo_indeseable_1  
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    indeseables/archivo_indeseable_2
```

Recalcando que tengo tanto deseables como indeseables en ese commit.

Ahora vamos a crear un archivo `.gitignore` anti-pelotudeces en la raíz de nuestra carpeta `git` con el contenido:

```
indeseables/
```

Luego de esto le vamos a dar:

```bash
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "add: gitignore added"
```

Luego vamos a borrar la carpeta de indeseables de nuestro index y arbol de commits con `git rm --cached`:

```bash
$ git rm --cached -r indeseables/
rm 'indeseables/archivo_indeseable_1'
rm 'indeseables/archivo_indeseable_2'
rm 'indeseables/archivo_indeseable_3'
...
```

Luego damos `git commit -m "fixed"`. Luego `git ls-tree -r HEAD` para ver:

```bash
$ git ls-tree HEAD -r
100644 blob 1b54db4cf10c1cfbe1d930dc317f3b06a7e191a1    .gitignore
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    deseables/archivo_deseable_1
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    deseables/archivo_deseable_10
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    deseables/archivo_deseable_2
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    deseables/archivo_deseable_3
...
```

Y ya no tenemos nuestros archivos indeseables, además que con el paso de gitignore ya no se van a añadir con tanta facilidad aquellos archivos.